# Javascript multidimensional array: object gets replaced

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have a function that is supposed to assign an object inside a two dimensional array. Somehow, the assignment overwrites the previous object in the array.

```
var markersN = {};
var markersNArray = []

function addMarkerN(lat, lng, id, name, key) {
    markersN[key] = {};
    var newMark = new google.maps.Marker({
        /*marker properties*/
    });
    markersNArray.push(newMark);     //This pushes every object to a one dimensional array just fine
    markersN[key][id] = newMark;     //This replaces the previous object in the markersN[key] array
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
for(var j=0; j<sekolah[i].nonlat.length; j++){
        addMarkerN(sekolah[i].nonlat[j], sekolah[i].nonlon[j], j, sekolah[i].nonname[j], sekolah[i].key);
    }
```

This is how I want the array to be:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
           (
               [0] => { /*marker object*/ }
               [1] => { /*marker object*/ }
           )
)
```

This is how it resulted:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
           (
               [1] => { /*marker object*/ }
           )
)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I prevent the function from overwriting the previous object in the array?

Thank you.

Comment: better to provide some sample data `sekolah` so we don't make assuption about structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting markersN[key] every time you call addMarker with a key that has been used before. Check if an entry in makersN for a given key exists already and only initialize if that is not the case.

```
if (typeof markersN[key] === 'undefined') {
  markersN[key] = {};
}
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn't paying attention to the declaration. Thank you very much, this solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `markersN[key] = {};` inside addMarkerN function so Every time you call this function the `markersN[key]` value assigned to Empty Array

Answer (score 0):

remove this line writen inside the function,

```
markersN[key] = {};
```